# how to add a lot data in nodejs to Neo4j?

Tags: javascript

I want to use Neo4j as a database. I want to add 100,000s of records into it. So far, searched for a good tutorial about it and could not find it.

Could any one show me a tutorial(i want a simple one) about how to do it in nodejs programs?

Comment: https://neo4j.com/developer/javascript/#_neo4j_for_javascript_developers

Comment: https://neo4j.com/blog/cypher-load-json-from-url/